# "Cannot read configuration file" when running ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, config

I recently decided to move all my VS projects to a dropbox folder so i don't have to carry my USB drive around all the time. I just copied all contents into the dropbox folder but when I run one of my ASP.NET projects, I get an HTTP error 500.19:

**Module**     IIS Web Core

**Notification**       Unknown

**Handler**    Not yet determined

**Error Code**     0x80070003

**Config Error**       Cannot read configuration file 

**Config File**    \?\I:\Documents\Schule\Praktikum\IHK-Projekt\WerIstWo\WerIstWo\web.config

I think it still looks for the config file in my usb drive, which I assigned the drive letter I:. How do I change this so it will my local the Dropbox directory with drive letter C:? What happens if I install Dropbox on another machine on D: drive? Will I get the same error?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: ok I fiddled around with the project properties. under servers I selected different options. it seems to work now but I have no idea why. I use the same options I used before, I only switched back and forth to try what would work. strange....

Comment: update: I still get this error if I use IIS. When I use the VS Development Server, I dont get this error.

Comment: ok when I insert my usb drive, it seems to work even with IISExpress. when I plug out my usb drive, I get the same error. this is really starting to bug me out...